# I want to add a line break when passing a string value to props

Tags: css, reactjs, react-props, line-breaks

I want to add a line break when passing a string value to props I have tried "Unsere \nLeidenschaft" and  {"Unsere \nLeidenschaft" } both but it is not working it break the line but it shows \n also with the text.

Here is my code:

I want to break the text of heading.

```
 <BgImageComponent
        DashSize={"35%"}
        Heading="Unsere Leidenschaft"
        SubHeading={"Das Team von Agento Aurum ist..."}
      />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution you have to seprate the strings and then put 
 it should be like this
{["Unsere", 
, "Leidenschaft"]}!

Answer (score 1):

if you update the css of heading element,
then
use the CSS property 
`white-space: pre;`
on the heading element
along with \n in the text
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Answer (score 0):

`\n` is for breaking lines in the terminal/console not in a website. A quick and dirty way to do it is by adding the `<br>` element below your code. But I strongly suggest looking up on how to add some space using `CSS`. I hope I helped and welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Hi I have already tried with <br> but when i run the application it shows <br> also in the display..

Comment: Did you use it after your ending `/>` tag? you have to use it outside of the element.

Comment: Yes I did it but it take it as a string and show it in the output